# Problems using start-process to call other powershell file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

EDIT::::See very bottom for current state of issue.

In the current set up, a batch file calls a powershell script with the following

```
powershell D:\path\powershellScript.v32.ps1 arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

I would like to convert this into a powershell script calling another powershell. However, I'm having issues using start process. This is what I currently have but upon execute I get the following

```
No application is associated with the specified file for this operation
```

This is the powershell that is executing

```
$powershellDeployment = "D:\path\powershellScript.v32.ps1"
$powershellArguments = "arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4"
Start-Process $powershellDeployment -ArgumentList $powershellArguements -verb runas -Wait
```

EDIT::::::

Due to the help below, I now have the following

```
$username = "DOMAIN\username"
$passwordPlainText = "password"     
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "$passwordPlainText" -asplaintext -force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username,$password

$powershellArguments = "D:\path\deploy.code.ps1", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3", "arg4"
Start-Process "powershell.exe" -credential $cred  -ArgumentList $powershellArguments
```

However, when I execute this script from a remote machine I get "access denied" errors, even though the username used has full administrator access to the machine

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should be using `Start-Process powershell.exe`, and passing the path to the script as the `-File` argument in your arg list. The `No application...` bit means that you don't have a default application set to work with .ps1 files on your machine. If you do the whole `Right Click -> Open With -> Select Application -> check "Use this program as default..."` tidbit on any .ps1 file, then the message goes away. My default program is notepad, so when I use `Start-Process` on a .ps1, it pops it up in that.

Edit:

To put it all together...

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-file C:\MyScript.ps1", "Arg1", "Arg2"
```

Or, if you define `$powershellArguments` as Keith says (`$powershellArguments = "-file C:\MyScript.ps1", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3", "arg4"`), then like this:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList $powershellArguments
```

Comment: I got the `no application...` to go away by removing the quotes around the content of `$powershellDeployment`. As of now the script executes as it should, however it asks for parameters, which means the ones I'm attempting to pass aren't getting passed properly

Comment: @mhopkins321 I've updated my answer to show you what the full command should look like. I tested this with a script that merely echoes the input args without issue.

Comment: would you be able to check out my edit to the post above and see if you can help with the new issue at all?

Comment: The format of StackOverflow really tries to limit one question per question, so, as such, I would suggest that you open a new question with a more detailed version of your edit (like the exact error message). HOWEVER, I strongly encourage you to [search[(http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+access+denied) the site for some other questions that might possibly be duplicates of your issue to see if your question has already been answered. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me as well.  I just found that the feedback is pretty bad if you make a mistake, so you want to try one parameter at a time if you can.  In my case, I'm writing the script I'm calling so I started out not requiring any parameters for that script and then added them in one at a time.

Answer (score 7):

Change this:

```
$powershellArguments = "arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4"
```

to

```
$powershellArguments = "arg1", "arg2", "arg3", "arg4"
```

The `-ArgumentList` parameter is expecting an array of arguments - not a single string with all the arguments.

Comment: made that change however i still get the same error `No applicatio
n is associated with the specified file for this operation`

Comment: edit: I got it to work by removing the quotes around `$powershellDeployment` however that particular script is asking for parameters manually, which means it the argument change didn't work